# How to change Host header in apache

Tags: apache-httpd

i have two vhosts (www.test1.com and www.test2.com).
I want for www.test2.com vhost change Host header to www.test1.com.
I have create config file but it doesn't work.

w1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.test1.com
ServerAlias test1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test1
ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/w1error.log
CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/w1requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

w2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.test2.com
ServerAlias test2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test2
RequestHeader set Host "www.test1.com"
ErrorLog /etc/httpd/logs/w2error.log
CustomLog /etc/httpd/logs/w2requests.log combined 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How are `w1.conf` and `w2.conf` included in the server’s configuration?

Comment: `Host` header is usualy set by client. It is used by server to know which virtual host is targetted by the request. Setting it "server-side" is quite useless. What is your goal ?

Comment: using IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf @StephenKitt

Comment: @binarym it is sample, i use Haproxy

Answer (score 1):

You can set any header with the directive `AddHeader` in httpd. However, I wonder what the point is in setting the `Host` field in a response.

The HTTP `Host` field is part of the request that goes *from* the client *to* the server. By means of this field, the web server (Apache httpd, in your case, but this is also true for nginx) decides which virtual host to use.

Since you are using HAProxy (as mentioned in one of your comments), I think you want to rewrite the field of the request. Just delete it and then append it:

```
    reqdel ^Host:
    reqadd Host:\ www.test1.com
```